# Access the frams of a Video During recording in iphone

Tags: iphone

Whether is it possible to access the frames of a Video at the time of recording?If yes,how?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible. Maybe you can send a feature request to Apple.

Regards,

Comment: Thanx Quentin.But by Apple's private API whether we can access the frames or not?If Yes,can you please give some link to do so?

Comment: Unfortunately (for you), I do not know private API. So I can not answer.

Regards,
Quentin

Answer (score 0):

This will be possible with the new APIs in iOS 4.

http://developer.apple.com/technologies/iphone/whats-new.html#api